# Java Picking a Layout Issue

Tags: java, swing, layout, panel, gridbaglayout

Hey guys I'm trying to make a screen with a navigation bar at the top and am unsure what layout would be the best to use. Basically I want the screen to look like:

```
[Nav Panel Up top, One row]
[            ^            ]
[            |            ]
[       Empty Panel       ]
[            |            ]
[            |            ]
[            |            ]
[            ^            ]
```

The nested panel contains the navigation buttons.

My question is, should I use a GridBagLayout and just set it to having like 10 rows and have the empty panel expand 9 of them or is there a better layout in Java that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Why not populate the menubar with the navigation buttons?

Comment: @mre The OP might want icons. (Although in that case, it's probably best to use a navigation bar as well as add the actions as menu entries.)

Comment: @Inerdial, Not sure I understand your argument. You can still add the icons to the navigation buttons..

Comment: You can add buttons to a menu bar? I was unaware of that. Would the code basically be JMenu home = new JButton("Home"); and from there it would be handled like a normal button?

Comment: @Tyler, Yes you can and yes they would.

Comment: @mre Hm, my bad, my OS X is showing I guess – I don't really think of a menu as a "container for buttons".

Answer (score 5):

The "navigation bar" sounds like it could as well be a component on its own. If the extra level of nesting isn't a problem, I'd just use [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), put the nav bar component [`NORTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#NORTH), and the empty panel (where the rest of the UI is I suppose) into the [`CENTER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#CENTER).

I prefer `GridBagLayout` for making complex controls that can't be split into subpanels anymore, and need layouts where there are a lot of edges to align – its flexibility is a little overkill for this case. (Of course it's still perfectly suitable for this task, just not the simplest way to accomplish it.)

Comment: +1 for BorderLayout. The panel inserted in the CENTER can still use any layout

Answer (score 4):

You wouldn't want to use 9 rows in `GridBagLayout` to hold one component; it is more powerful than that.  Instead give the `GridBagConstraints` for the navigation panel a [`weighty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#weighty) of `0` and the empty panel a `weighty` of `1` (or any positive number).  This will cause the empty panel to take up any extra space.